# SharedPreference clear() throwing nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to clear a list, for which I need to clear the SharedPreference. But on doing so, I get a nullpointerexception.
Here's my code. -

```
MainActivity.savedLogName.edit().clear().commit();
MainActivity.savedLogNumber.edit().clear().commit();
MainActivity.savedLogTime.edit().clear().commit();
```

I've also tried using remove(), but the same error persists. Here's the code using remove()

```
MainActivity.savedLogName.edit().remove("logName").commit();
MainActivity.savedLogNumber.edit().remove("logNumber").commit();
MainActivity.savedLogTime.edit().remove("logTime").commit();
```

Note - savedlogName, savedLogNumber and savedLogTime are static variables declared in MainActivity. I'm calling them from a different activity class.

From MainActivity -

```
savedLogName = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        savedLogNumber = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        savedLogTime = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    logName = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(savedLogName.getString("logName", null), ",")));
    logNumber = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(savedLogNumber.getString("logNumber", null), ",")));
    logTime = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(savedLogTime.getString("logTime", null), ",")));
```

I want logName, logNumber and logTime to be intialized null if sharedPreference is empty. That doesn't happen. It just initializes to old values like it was never cleared.

Comment: Add the code where you initialize the statics savedLogName, Number etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREFS", 0).edit().clear().commit();
```

remove all your prefs

or get the editor and clear like this

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Hi, this works, but the the log just keeps coming back everytime I restart the app, because SharedPreference variables are initialized in onCreate() of MainActivity. How do I avoid that?

Comment: What i understand by this is inside onCreate() you are clearing the shared pref and printing some log msg right? If thats the case then put it in a if statement if sharepref is cleared (null or empty) skip log msg.  (Please post the main activity code it will help to debug).

Comment: I meant call log. I've just edited and posted the MainActivity code. Could you please take a look

Comment: I want logName, logNumber and logTime to be intialized null if sharedPreference is empty. That doesn't happen. It just initializes to old values like it was never cleared.

Comment: inside onCreate() first you check the shared pref if its empty then initialize the variables based on that. or when you clear shared pref  store some flag and just check that flag before you initialize the variables.

Comment: I've done `if(savedLogName != null && savedLogNumber != null && savedLogTime != null) {
            logName = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(savedLogName.getString("logName", null), ",")));
            logNumber = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(savedLogNumber.getString("logNumber", null), ",")));
            logTime = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(savedLogTime.getString("logTime", null), ",")));
        }else{
            logName = null;
            logNumber = null;
            logTime = null;
        }` Still doesn't work. The if loop gets executed.